# Different names for Dovid in regular Selichos vs Yom Kippur Selichos

Tags: names, yom-kippur, nuschaot, selichot, king-david

Why do we refer to Dovid Hamelech as "Mashiach Tzidkecha" in Selichos (towards the end, paragraph begins with those words) except on Yom Kippur when we refer to him as "Dovid Avdecha" (in the same location as in normal selichos)?

Comment: Bobo, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for your questions! We try to keep it to one question per post for organizational reasons, but I encourage you to ask more questions here http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask Please consider registering your account to keep those contributions together. I look forward to seeing you around!